# Why can't compile std::views::take(std::uint64_t{})?

Tags: c++, stl, standards, c++20, std-ranges

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <ranges>

int main()
{
    auto const il = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    auto const n1 = std::int32_t{3};
    auto const n2 = std::uint32_t{3};
    auto const n3 = std::int64_t{3};
    auto const n4 = std::uint64_t{3};

    il | std::views::take(n1); // ok
    il | std::views::take(n2); // ok
    il | std::views::take(n3); // ok
    il | std::views::take(n4); // error
}
```

See [online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/M8Kq8zhx1)

**Why can't compile** `std::views::take(std::uint64_t{})`**?**

Comment: fyi - working in 11.2 -  live - https://godbolt.org/z/hnKPn4soz

Comment: It seems a bug of gcc 11.1.

Comment: https://wg21.link/p2367r0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`range | std::views::take(n)` is expression equivalent to `std::ranges::take_view(range, n)`, which takes [a `ranges::range_difference_t<V>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/take_view/take_view).

Following the aliases through, gcc 11.1 doesn't want to consider `unsigned long` as usable where a `long` is wanted

Answer (score 3):

Prior to [P2367](https://wg21.link/p2367), the default case of `views::take(E, F)` was specified to be expression-equivalent to `ranges::take_view{E, F}`. Note the braces.

`ranges::take_view<V>` takes a `range_difference_t<V>` (which is signed) as its second argument. List-initialization rejects narrowing (e.g. attempting to initialize a `ptrdiff_t` with a `uint64_t`), so your example was rejected.

However, now `views::take(E, F)` is specified to be expression-equivalent to `ranges::take_view(E, F)`. With parentheses. Which means no check for narrowing, which means passing a `uint64_t` is totally fine.

libstdc++ implemented that change on [Apr 30](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/commit/6e00d9bb113b531be15bc71cad2f1742648ba18a) which I guess was too late for gcc 11.1 but that change is there in gcc 11.2, which accepts your code.